# New Server 2012 Standard domain controller will not boot after power outage (STOP: 0xc00002e2)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

We are in the process of migrating from Small Business Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 with Exchange 2010.  On Saturday we promoted a new Windows Server 2012 VM to a domain controller on the domain (allowing Server Manager to update the schema) and everything went fine.  Later that day, the server lost power.

Now, when booting this VM, we are getting STOP 0xc00002e2.  Logging into DSRM we can see in the event log the following error:

> EventID 1003 Active Directory Domain Services could not be
>   initialized.
>
> The directory service cannot recover from this error.
>
> User Action 
>   Restore the local directory service from backup media.
>
> Additional Data Error value:
>   -566 JET_ErrDbTimeTooOld, dbtime on page smaller than dbtimeBefore in record

We had not yet setup a backup of this server, so we can not "Restore the local directory service from backup media."

My question is, what is the best course of action here?

The existing SBS 2003 server is still online and functional.  Can we force a removal of the new server and just re-promote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Metadata cleanup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736378%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) on the failed domain controller. It's gone.

Seize the FSMO roles if necessary. Move them back to the old DC for now, if you had moved them to the failed DC.

Build a new VM (from scratch. Don't try to salvage the failed one.) Promote it to domain controller.

Gracefully transfer the FSMOs to the new DC if desired.

Install an uninterruptable power supply so that this doesn't happen again.

Set up backups so that this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Thankfully we had not moved the FSMO roles yet.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall. Bad things happen - this was shitty timing for the pwoer outage. At the end, a reinstall is fast and makes sure you dont ahve any issues with that server.